# How can i run .Jar file on Aws ec2 without login and cli?

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I've created a java-server that is connected with firebase. This server is used to listen to firebase changes and update the database accordingly. For making it run all the time I've added CountDownLatch in my main function here is my code.

```
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    while (true)
    {
        nextGamesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                nextGames = snapshot;
                setNextGame(nextGames);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                System.out.println(error.toString());
                System.out.println("3");
            }
        });
        latch.await();
    }
```

I'm sharing the above code because i'm new in java and really apreciate suggestions if there is a better way to do this.

Let's come to the point. I've packaged my whole project in a jar file and deployed that file on my Aws ec2 instance. Everything is running fine except I always need to invoke this class from my personal pc. I want this file to run on its own, without the need of invoking it from an external system. I've taken a look at tomcat but it works on an HTTP request or let me know if I'm understanding tomcat incorrectly.

So the question is. How can I run this Jar on my instance once for all time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploying to AWS is very broad topic and involves ASG and Loadbalancing for high availability, Scalability and Fault Tolerance. Jenkins/Terraform/Docker/Packer for CICD.

But just to answer your question, use the "User Data" feature of the Ec2 instance and specify the command you want to run. Mentioning the command in the User data will make sure the command runs when the Ec2 is started.

For example,

```
java -cp /home/ec2-user/App.jar com.test.MySampleClass
```

Assumption: App.jar is already available in the Ec2 instance.

If it is a web application, then you can deploy to tomcat. Again use the Ec2 User data feature and mention the bunch of commands to download tomcat and start it.

Comment: I'm trying to run my file using this command but it isn't working #!/bin/bash java -jar /home/ubuntu/javaServer/fileName.jar. I've added this on my user-data of AWS. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: When you say, it is not working, what do you mean.. Did you run it manually to see whats happening? Also can you check /var/log/cloud-init-output.log. this log file captures the execution of user data scripts.

Comment: Just fixed it using this link 
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/.
Basically, user-data only works on the first launch, to make it work on every time the server is started from a stop state you've to configure your user data script and cloud-init directives with a mime multi-part file.